# How can i access from txt to jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I make a movie theater with JButtons, and I keep them in a JPanel.

In my txt, I have `0` and `1`. I read digit and put it to arraylist. When I `setBackground()` my JButtons if came `0` I set green, if came `1` I set red. But when code run all of them are green. How can I fix that?

I try repaint and dispose. But it didn't work.

```
if(controls.get(n) == 0){
    button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    //  repaint();
    //  dispose();
}
if(controls.get(n) == 1){
    //  button.setBackground(Color.RED);
    repaint();
    //  dispose();
}
n++;
```

Comment: I am not pretty sure about your question. However, you could also use a `else` in your `if`: `if (controls.get(n) == 0) { /* set green */ } else { /* set red */ }` Maybe it would be helpful for us, if you post a bit more code (only the relevant parts).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider providing a [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would result in better responses and less guess work

Comment: I try it that and it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you allways get 0? In case 1 you do not set the color. And as i can see, controls is a list of Objects so you should use the equals method to compare the values

Comment: I print it and i checked it. I also get "1"

Comment: @MadProgrammer For example, I will create jbuttons with two for loops (like a matrix). i=2,j=2. And i read from txt file"00110011". And it must be "GREEN,GREEN,RED,RED,GREEN,GREEN,RED,RED"

Comment: That's all fine and nice, but you should try and provide a runnable example of your problem, this way we know what it is you're doing, a picture says a thousand words, code describes your problem just as well...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line `button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);`

`button` is the reference to one single button, and you only update that JButton's colour.
The below code updates an array of JButtons

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[100];
for(int n = 0; n<buttons.length; n++) {
    buttons[n] = new JButton();
    if(controls.get(n) == 0){
        buttons[n].setBackground(Color.GREEN); // update button number n
        repaint();
        dispose();
    }
    if(controls.get(n) == 1){
        buttons[n].setBackground(Color.RED); // update button number n
        repaint();
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i create the buttons, i setBackground. In this way it has to be.

Comment: I dont really understand, you dont want to change background after you have created them?

Comment: No when i create, i want to setbackground.

Comment: Well, above I create an array of JButtons (dont kow if that it's exactly how you want them, but is only an example). After creation you have to call setBackground(), as above. Since you have them in an array, you have to loop over all buttons.